# DOMDocument interface for python lxml

Tags: python, dom, html-parsing, lxml

I have written a small application that needs to have access to the DOM representation of the underlying HTML page. Lxml is really great but I have not been able to find such an interface. Does someone know if one exists or if there is another tool that does it?

Answer (score 2):

[According to the lxml documentation](http://lxml.de/sax.html#interfacing-with-pulldom-minidom), it's possible to use lxml to parse the document, and its SAX parser can interface with the Python xml.dom.pulldom module to create a DOM object. From the documentation, the code might look like:

```
from xml.dom.pulldom import SAX2DOM
handler = SAX2DOM()
lxml.sax.saxify(tree, handler)
dom = handler.document
```

Answer (score 2):

There is an [example of parsing HTML](http://lxml.de/parsing.html#parsing-html) at [lxml site](http://lxml.de/):

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> from StringIO import StringIO

>>> broken_html = "<html><head><title>test<body><h1>page title</h3>"

>>> parser = etree.HTMLParser()
>>> tree   = etree.parse(StringIO(broken_html), parser)

>>> result = etree.tostring(tree.getroot(),
...                         pretty_print=True, method="html")
>>> print(result)
<html>
  <head>
    <title>test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>page title</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can access tree elements using methods `tree.find, tree.findall, tree.iter, tree.xpath` and other. For example:

```
>>> tree.getroot().getchildren()
[<Element head at 0x4f4ad38>, <Element body at 0x4f4ad80>]

>>> tree.getroot()..find('body')
<Element body at 0x4f4ad80>
```

You can also use standard Python XML interfaces, as it was pointed by Kurt:

```
>>> from xml.dom.pulldom import SAX2DOM
>>> handler = SAX2DOM()
>>> lxml.sax.saxify(tree, handler)

>>> dom = handler.document
>>> print(dom.firstChild.localName)
```

But remember that [lxml API is superior to dom/minidom](http://jaytaylor.com/blog/2009/11/01/for-python-lxml-superior-to-domminidom/).

Answer (score 1):

I've used [minidom](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.dom.minidom.html) (particularly example 19.7.2) for several projects where DOM representation was needed.

It's proven useful for parsing xml configuration files and cleaning up poorly written HTML.  I'd like to instil your confidence in minidom because it has been such a useful tool in practice!

Answer (score 0):

[minidom](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.dom.minidom.html?highlight=minidom#module-xml.dom.minidom) ?

Comment: Yes was considering this one but was looking for maybe a better solution for the following reasons. First it sounds me that lxml is far better and quicker, and last because it seems a not very good implementation ( I think i have read something about these lines about trying to avoid minidom , but I have no strong opinion myself on the latter)